# Memory Allocation Error with Principal Value Integral

Tags: numerical-integration

I'm getting a `SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]` error with some arguments to `S[x]` in the following Mathematica code

```
J[x_] := 0.01 x^3/10^2 Exp[-x/10];
n[x_] := 1/(Exp[x] - 1);
f[x_?NumericQ /; x >= 0] := 2 Pi J[x] (n[x] + 1);
f[x_?NumericQ /; x < 0] := 2 Pi J[Abs[x]] n[Abs[x]];
S[x_]:=1/(2 Pi) NIntegrate[f[y]/(x - y), {y, -Infinity, x, Infinity}, 
  Method -> PrincipalValue]
```

For example S[-50] throws this error. However, if I put the limit of integration as an argument I see good convergence of the integral for such values of `x`:

```
S[x_,limit_]:=1/(2 Pi) NIntegrate[f[y]/(x - y), {y, -limit, x, limit}, 
  Method -> PrincipalValue]
```

I've also tried this integral in Julia and it doesn't seem to have any problems calculating it. What's going on?

Comment: I get no error (V13.1 Mac M1 Max): https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekspb.png

Comment: Can you report the version of Mathematica and operating system you are using?

Comment: Version 13.1:  S[-50] returns -0.069741

Comment: I'm using version 12.1 unfortunately.